# Filling as it is data from stored procedure to Datatable

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am experiencing weird behavior while filling data from a stored procedure to a `DataTable`.

What I am filling is:

Output from stored procedure:

```
MINI COMBO   
     Coke Float
```

Which is constructed in `Stuff` by adding `CHAR(13)` after MINI COMBO and some space before Coke Float.

Reflect in `DataTable` after fill :

```
     Coke Float   
MINI COMBO
```

This is really new to me, please help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: please provide some more information: Who is this data generated? Who is it filled into the table?

Comment: Provide your code, what you have tried? And explain more clearly what you need.

Comment: I am using SqlDataAdapter.fill to fill my DataTable.

Comment: Is your issue the order of the results is different than what you expect?  Note that ordering is nondeterministic unless your query specifies and `ORDER BY` clause.  Post your code if you need help with that.

Comment: SELECT 
  TXNID, 
  ItemName = STUFF(
  (
   SELECT
    
    Case When Level > 0
     Then
     Case When ItemName like '%(%'
       Then
       ','+ItemName
      Else
       '( '+ ItemName+' '
     End
    Else
     CHAR(13) + 
     Space(Spaces * 5) + ItemName+'   '
    End
   FROM 
    #ARLines_2 x1
   WHERE TXNID = x.TXNID
   Order By Spaces
   FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, '')
 FROM 
  #ARLines_2 AS x
 GROUP BY ID

Comment: my stored procedure is giving me exact output as imensioned above but DataTable is not filling it as SP returns.
What my query returns is
    MINI COMBO   
     Coke Float   
But DataAdapter.fill fills as
     Coke Float   
MINI COMBO

Answer (score 0):

This is an ordering issue. The order that is output from your stored procedure can change at any time for a variety of reasons, unless, you specify an ORDER BY statement.

For example:

```
SELECT TXNID, ItemName = STUFF( ( SELECT Case When Level > 0 Then Case When 
ItemName like '%(%' Then ','+ItemName Else '( '+ ItemName+' ' End Else CHAR(13) + Space(Spaces * 5) + ItemName+' ' End 
FROM #ARLines_2 x1 WHERE TXNID = x.TXNID Order By Spaces FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, '') FROM #ARLines_2 AS x 
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY ItemName DESC
```

I suspect however, you have some sort of hierarchy order that you want to show in your drop down. i.e. parent child relationship. If this is the case, you will need to include some sort of hierarchy identifier in the order by statement

Comment: Hay sarin i wonder the data is already sorted order in the table so i skip  the order by. But Order by works for me. Thanx alot. can you please explain what happened there

Comment: the order that the data is physically stored in the table is not directly related to the order that you see output from your SP. It can depend on different factors such as Indexes (clustered or non-clustered), order of insert, type of index used by the optimizer when executing your SP. The only way to guarantee the order is to specify an ORDER BY statement. Hope that helps! Mark me as answered and up vote if helpful!